# Interpreting coefficients in MLR model with interaction term

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients

$\hat{IQ} = 100 + 0.1*gender + 4.3*athletic+ 0.3*gender * athletic$

This is a model with 2 binary predictors: gender (0 = female, 1 = male), athletic (0 = no, 1 = yes) and an interaction term.

$\hat{B}_0 = 100$: the expected IQ score is 100 for a female who is non-athletic.

$\hat{B}_1 = 0.1$: the expected change in IQ is 0.1 units for a male rather than a female, given that he is non-athletic.

$\hat{B}_2 = 4.3$: the expected change in IQ is 4.3 units for an athlete vs. non-athlete, given that the person is female.

Are the above interpretations correct? And now comes the tricky part with interpreting the interaction term between two categorical variables. I've looked at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56784/how-to-interpret-the-interaction-term-in-lm-formula-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) post and its suggestion on rewriting the model in a different format; however, I do not see how that would help me interpret $\hat{B}_3$, the interaction coefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Male athlete:** 100 + 0.1 * 1 + 4.3 * 1 + 0.3 * 1 = 100+0.1+4.3+0.3 = 104.7

Without the interaction term the male athlete would have 104.4. The interaction term does only have an impact on the dependent variable for male athletes.

**Male non-athlete:** 100 + 0.1 *1 + 4.3 *0 + 0.3 *0  = 100 + 0.1 = 100.1

**Female athlete:** 100 + 0.1 *0  + 4.3 *1 + 0.3 *0 = 100 + 4.3 = 104.3

**Female non-athlete:** 100 + 0.1 *0 + 4.3 *0 + 0.3 *0 = 100

Comment: Yes, I understand. But how exactly would you interpret the interaction coefficient in this context?

Comment: B1 = difference female & male non-athletes B2 = difference female non-athletes & female athletes (B1 + B3)= different male athletes and male non-athletes

Comment: So I can't interpret just B3? I have to interpret it in terms of B1 + B3?

Comment: B3 is the difference between i) the effects of women doing sports and ii) the effects of men doing sports