# How to examine gender effects in Mixed Effects Models?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model

In my main analysis, I observed that people had better overall performance (0=failed, 1=success) in the manipulation condition than in the control condition. This was a within-subjects design.

This was the model I used:

```
fit <- glmer(performance~condition + (1|id), data = df, family=binomial())
```

In the descriptive analysis, I can see that males had better performance than females.
I want to examine if that difference is significant, as an exploratory analysis.
How can I add gender to the model?

Comment: In the same way you would add `condition` to the model. It would be `performance~condition + gender + (1|id)`. But it depends on if you want to control for `condition`.

Comment: If I do that, I'll get the gender effect on the overall performance, right? I'd want to evaluate the gender effect specifically on the manipulation condition.

Comment: Are you thinking of interacting condition with gender: `performance ~ condition * gender + (1|id)`? To learn more about interactions and how to interpret them see eg. [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/122246/237901) and [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/56784/237901).

Comment: @Olivia I think you just want `condition ~ gender + (1|id)`?

Comment: Thank you! I wanted an interaction effect like @dipetkov mentioned